# Data is not stored in my Database - why so?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an insert function in my database helper class and now I created an object of database helper class in my main class and call the insert function. But when I fill my variables into insert function, it gives me ** bottom red line error**. I can't understand what to do after that, so please help me.

**Code of insert function of database helper class**

[image]
**code of insert function of main class**
[image]
**Image of error**
[image]
**Image of datatype**
[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hover your mouse over the red line to check the error and post here the error message.

Comment: I give image of error in my question please check.

Answer (score 0):

From your screen shots, there are 7 parameters for method. Check data type of method and the values you are passing for the method. Since method parameter count and your method input parameters were matching.

Comment: Sir I update my question an attach a screen shot of datatype. Please check

Comment: SQLiteDatabase sql_db;
with this object you are trying to call your method. This is not correct. It does not Call your insert method. It call SQLiteDatabase insert method.